# Select Map<Integer, Integer> using mybatis

Tags: mybatis

I want to select Map for each record. Result class looks like

```
public class Mapping {
    private String name;
    private Map<Integer, Integer>;
}
```

SQL table has only three columns namely `name, id, partner_id`.

How can I create Map of Id to Partner Id for each name using mybatis?

Answer (score 0):

you can use sqlSession.selectForMap, and give mybatis the column which will be processed as the key of map , such as name. then it will return

```
Map<String,Map<String,Object>>
```

as a result, but the value is Map, key is the column name, you need to transform it .